# Multiple endpoints - public/internal

Tags: c#, wcf

I want to expose 2 endpoints on my WCF service. First offers standard methods for users over HTTP, second one offers "administrator-only" method ovet net.tcp.

I have only 1 class, that implements both ServiceContracts exposed by endpoints, like that:

```
public class ComputingModuleProvider : IComputingModuleProvider, IComputingModuleAdminProvider
```

My App.Config looks like this:

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ComputingModuleBehaviour" name="ComputingModuleProvider.ComputingModuleProvider">
    <endpoint address="ComputingModuleProvider" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ComputingModuleProvider.IComputingModuleProvider" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />        
    <endpoint address="ComputingModuleAdminProvider" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="ComputingModuleProvider.IComputingModuleAdminProvider" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8091/ComputingModuleProvider"/>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8092/ComputingModuleProvider" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

Now the situation is that I have the service on the server-computer in our office and the client is on my personal computer (**but both of them are connected to local network**).

Still, I had to add an exception to server firewall and allow communication on ports 8091 and 8092 in order to be able to add service reference and generate proxy on client side. With this exception allowed, I can add service reference using both net.tcp and http base adress.

The problem is, that I see both ServiceContracs for each base adress, like in the image below:

[image]

I expected, that for net.tcp I would only see `IComputingModuleAdminProvider` and for http, I would see `IComputingModuleProvider`.

I also tried to exclude port 8092 from allowed ports on server firewall - that resulted in being able to add service reference only by using http base adress, but still, I could see both Service contracts exposed, like in image above.
So the administrator-only method is available over http as well.

**Question:**

Am I doing something wrong in my app.config file or is this the standard behaviour? I know I am on the same local network, but still, I had to add the exception in firewall, thus I expected, that `IComputingModuleAdminProvider` would not be available over http protocol.¨

**UPDATE:**
Ass suggested by Otiel, if I create new ServiceContract like this:

```
public class ComputingModuleAdminProvider : IComputingModuleAdminProvider
```

And mark it as a new `<service>` in App.Config, I can separate the admin and standard interface.

Comment: Just a guess here: did you try defining two `<service>` with only one `<host>` for each one (http for the first and net.tcp for the second) in your *app.config*?

Comment: I have tested it the way you suggested and its working - I defined 2 ServiceContracts and separated them in 2 `<service>` tags in App.Config. After that, each ServiceContract is available only from endpoint defined under `<service>`. Im just a bit confused, cause a lot of tutorials and examples uses the way I described in my question. Like this one for example: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/830986/Multiple-Service-Contract-in-WCF  or in the book Learning WCF from L.M. Bustamante